# Group data by daily and update in monthly and yearly table in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am beginner to cassandra and have to do this..

I have a table schema of daily table

```
CREATE TABLE daily(
id text,
date timestamp,
total_used counter,
PRIMARY KEY(id, date)
)
```

I need to get all total_used value date-wise and then after getting those value i need to update it in month wise table (which is already there)
Table Schema for Month table

```
CREATE TABLE month(
id text,
year text,
month text
total_used counter,
PRIMARY KEY((id,year),month)
)
```

Then after updating it in monthly table i need to update same year wise in yearly table

After reading alot or articles i took approach to use GROUP BY on PRIMARY KEY in daily table. But failed on how to update same in monthly and yearly table.

Can anyone help me in same?

Comment: so you updating monthly tables after you close the month?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it like that. The other way round is we are updating side by side once daily is getting updated.

Actually some data from x date to y date was not updated to moonthly and yearly table so need to rite queries to update that in monthly and tearly table

Comment: @AlexOtt Actually, some data from x date to y date was not updated to the month wise and year wise table so need to write queries to update that in monthly and yearly table

Comment: if you not updating the monthly/yearly data in realtime, then you can change type from counter to bigint, for example, and update the fields

Comment: @AlexOtt We are updating tables in real time.